# Defining Variable's Data Type While Assigning New?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, types

i'm linked a MovieClip class object to my project, and i will programatically add it to the display list.  is there a difference between defining the variable's data type and not doing so?  neither produce a runtime error.

```
//var datatype
var rectangle:Block = new Block();
addChild(rectangle);

//no var datatype
var rectangle = new Block();
addChild(rectangle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActionScript, it doesn't make much of a difference, AS isn't very strict in these situations. But it is a best-practice to set the datatype, and it allows the IDE to give code-hints.